# How to add new "Sort by" filters in Magento 1.9 CE?

Tags: theme, magento-community, filter, sorting, magento-1.9

I'm new to magento. I'm using Magento 1.9 CE Today it's the 4th day of my trying to customise magento. My biggest problem is with the filters, I am creating a fashion-store template. So i need filters: size, color, manufacture, brand, etc 
I trying to archive this with default function "Sort by" but I can't still find anything on it and how to implement in magento custom theme. I don't like "premium $" extensions. I am still searching for solution. If you managed some similar project, can you help me to find the right way?
**Thanks**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I'll give it a go.
You can edit the attributes you want in the backend `Catalog->Attribtues->Manage Attribtues`.
Search for the attribute you need (size for example) and edit it.
There should be a field there called `Use In Layered Navigation`. If you select for it `Filtrable with results` or `Filtrable no results` it will make your attribute available in th e layered navigation. I mean the customers will be able to filter the products in a category based on any value of the size attribute.

Same goes for `Use In Search Results Layered Navigation`. If you select `Yes` the customers will be able to filter the search results on the values of the size attribute.

There is also the field `Used for Sorting in Product Listing`. If you set that to `Yes` then the customer will be able to sort the products based on the size attribute.

Do the same for all your other attributes.

Comment: I just answered a similar question, you are too quick :)